# Left Join / OR - [SQL ACCESS]

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I try to manage a delivery team.
That's why, i want to display a table . The first line will be completed by day.
And the following rows will be filled with the states and their durations .
The row "date" must contain all days of the month . Even if nobody works.

```
- First table (typeState) -
deliveryStatusDuration  //State Time (seconds)  INTEGER
deliveryStatus  //Type Status                   INTEGER
startStatus  //Start of the state               DATE
endStatus  //End of the state                   DATE
deliveryCarNum  //deliverer identifier          INTEGER


- Second table (dateTable) -
dateInt // Just an integer (from 1 to 31)       INTEGER
```

My SQL Request :

```
SELECT SUM(deliveryStatusDuration) AS DURATION, deliveryStatus, datetable.dateInt
FROM datetable                      
LEFT JOIN typeState ON datetable.dateInt = DAY(typeState.startStatus)
WHERE deliveryCarNum=:CarNum      
AND startStatus >= :DateStart
AND endStatus <= :DateEnd        
AND (typeState.startStatus Is Null)
OR (typeState.deliveryStatus Is Null)  
OR datetable.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd)    
GROUP BY datetable.dateInt, deliveryStatus
```

The problem Is that whatever the month used, all information is displayed .
I think "OR" destroy my "AND", so I don't have those days when a status begins.
For exemple, if a delivery man begins to deliver at May 4, 2016 and ends May 8, 2016; my request doesn't appear August 4. :
1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10...31

Comment: Fix the parentheses to implement the logic you really want.

Comment: Also if you want all of the date integers to be included move the typestate conditions from the where clause to the join on statement. Putting them in the where clause will limit your entire result set by them whereas putting them as conditions of the join will limit what is allows to matched and be included from the typestate table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the `WHERE` clause you want is:

```
WHERE deliveryCarNum = :CarNum AND
      startStatus >= :DateStart AND
      endStatus <= :DateEnd AND   
      (typeState.startStatus Is Null OR
       typeState.deliveryStatus Is Null OR
       datetable.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd)   
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon's comment implies. You want to group your ORs together.

```
AND (THIS OR THAT OR THEOTHER)
```

rather than

```
AND (THIS)
OR (THAT)
OR (THEOTHER)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work ! :

```
SELECT SUM(deliveryStatusDuration) AS DURATION, deliveryStatus, datetable.dateInt
FROM datetable                      
LEFT JOIN typeState ON datetable.dateInt = DAY(typeState.startStatus)
WHERE deliveryCarNum = :CarNum AND
  startStatus >= :DateStart AND
  endStatus <= :DateEnd AND   
  (
   typeState.startStatus Is Null OR
   typeState.deliveryStatus Is Null OR
   datetable.dateInt <= DAY(:DateEnd)   
  )   
GROUP BY datetable.dateInt, deliveryStatus
```

This request select right lines (whatever the date).
But i fail to see every day..

```
LEFT JOIN typeState ON datetable.dateInt = DAY(typeState.startStatus)  OR ((DAY(typeState.startStatus) Is Null))
```